# Is there a way to use my JS files in React? Export or script tags etc?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function

I have a JS file which makes some elements appear/disappear on mouseenter/click. This works fine in normal JS. I am now building my app using React, but I can't get this functionality. I have tried `export`/`import` as you can see, and `script:src` in my `index.html`.

```
// Options appear on hover
export const optionsBtn = document.querySelector("[data-function='options']");
export const hiddenButtons = [...document.querySelectorAll(".hidden")];

export function optionsHover() {
  hiddenButtons.forEach(button => button.classList.toggle("hidden"));
}

optionsBtn.addEventListener("mouseenter", optionsHover);
optionsBtn.addEventListener("click", optionsHover);
```

Unsure as to how I'd get this code to work in React.
Am I missing something here?

Comment: If you are loading the file as a normal script on the web page then you cannot use module syntax (i.e. remove `export`). Not sure how this is related to React though. The file will create global variables and functions that you can use normally in all your JS code.

Comment: Trying to mix direct DOM manipulation with React is a nightmare. React is designed to take over management of DOM manipulation. It's probably possible to get this to work, but would involve a lot of jumping through hoops and binding to specific stages of the React component lifecycle. Rewrite your existing code in React style instead.

Comment: This link gives a good explanation on how to add JS to REACT : https://developers.sap.com/tutorials/react-add-javascript.html

Comment: @Quentin thank you. I guess i'm just being lazy. I thought it was possible for the two to work together (React and additional javascript) where necessary.

Comment: @Adds — No it doesn't. It's a (somewhat out of date) guide to adding React to a webpage. It has *nothing* about making it play nicely with already existing JS that interacts with the DOM.

Comment: @Quentin Thanks for the Info. Will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**NOTE**

> Its not best practice. DOM should not be manipulated directly
>   when using reactJS, you should not do that ideally, as react takes
>   care of DOM manipulation and it is highly optimised for that.

If you have to use your JS and rewriting it using React Component is not an option,

You can import your script using `require('yourfile.js')` but since your JS is trying to access dom elements you would want to execute the JS after the dom elements are rendered.

You can do this by requiring the `yourfile.js` from the `componentDidMount` [lifecycle method](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount) of your root app component.

Below is an example,

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import "./style.css";

let myjs;

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    myjs = require("./yourfile"); // Import file here after component mounted
    myjs.optionsHover();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <button data-function="options">Option</button>
          <button class="hidden">Button</button>
          <button class="hidden">Button</button>
          <button class="hidden">Button</button>
          <button class="hidden">Button</button>
          <button class="hidden">Button</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Here is a [full snippet](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-zhvfsm).

Comment: No, its not best practice. DOM should not be manipulated directly when using reactJS, you should not do that ideally, as react takes care of DOM manipulation and it is highly optimised for that.

Answer (score 0):

you can try `import 'yourfile.js'` or `require('your js file')`

```
const myScript = require('script')

then myScript.something()
```

Comment: That would make the JS *run* but not work. The DOM elements wouldn't be available in time. It would throw an exception when it hit the last two lines.

Answer (score 0):

This is *not the ideal approach*. However if you want to use that, here's the work around:

1. Convert your JS code into a simple JS class in your React App
2. Create class's instance (object) in the respective React component
3. Bind the events of the React component with the said object's
   function

This would be sufficient to use your existing JS within the React App.